# Recreate Package.resolved

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I deleted my `Package.resolved` because it was refusing to update to the latest package versions.

Is there any way to regenerate it? I've tried resetting package caches and updating to latest versions but both failed to regenerate the `Package.resolved` file.